# How to fetch data using a session attribute? help me to fix this

Tags: java, html, jsp

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM stakehoders WHERE email = ${sessionEmail}"
```

here `sessionEmail` is the session attribute.
in java page i assign `sessionEmail` as follows

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("sessionEmail",email);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Using Prepared Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) tutorial. The interesting part will be:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM stakehoders WHERE email = ?";
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
stmt.setString(1, request.getSession().getAttribute("sessionEmail");
```

Comment: thak you brother!!

Comment: @DinuwanKalubowila if it helped, please accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
String sessionEmail = session.getAttribute("sessionEmail");

PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM stakehoders WHERE email = ?");
stmt.setString(1, sessionEmail);
```

Comment: String sql = "SELECT * FROM stakehoders where email = '"+session.getAttribute("sessionEmail")+"'";

Comment: You should not do it that way!

Comment: @DinuwanKalubowila your attempt has a [sql injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) security vulnerability.

Comment: Please provide an explanation to why this is an answer